# Is std::cout with no apparent target a bad thing to leave in released code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std, cout

I will be releasing a Windows videogame soon. I have left in various places in my code

```
std::cout << "Debug stuff" << calculateThisAndThat() << "\n";
```

This is of course printed in the console window in **Debug** mode.

```
    void openConsoleWindow() {
#ifdef _DEBUG /// console window opens only in **debug** mode
        AllocConsole();

        HANDLE handle_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        int hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_out, _O_TEXT);
        FILE* hf_out = _fdopen(hCrt, "w");
        setvbuf(hf_out, NULL, _IONBF, 1);
        *stdout = *hf_out;

        HANDLE handle_in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
        hCrt = _open_osfhandle((long) handle_in, _O_TEXT);
        FILE* hf_in = _fdopen(hCrt, "r");
        setvbuf(hf_in, NULL, _IONBF, 128);
        *stdin = *hf_in;

        HWND hwndMyWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        SetWindowPos(hwndMyWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_DRAWFRAME | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // ALWAYS ON TOP
#endif
    }
```

In **Release** mode, nothing gets obviously printed anywhere (or so I think). Should I add

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
```

around EVERY std::cout in my code, for any reason at all?

Comment: You could just disable `std::cout`, e.g., by using `std::cout.setstate(std::ios_base::badbit);`.

Comment: That will still execute the calculations though.

Comment: @krzaq: sure - but it seems the question wasn't target at doing less work but rather at not producing output (and I have seen code where disabling the code would be undesirable but I wouldn't endorse corresponding coding practices).

Comment: Unless your codebase is huge, I am pretty sure you can get rid of the majority of those with a regex.

Comment: Basically you should have created some "DebugLog" wrapper for logging at the beginning, so your codebase would call some DebugLog( ... ) and that would be possible to define as empty thing with `#ifndef DEBUG_LOG` or something like that. If you keep it like that since start, it's then easy to build release without logging. With more complex scheme you may actually use logging level, and keep the code there even for release in non-performance code. Then allow some configuration of logging level ("none" = default), so in case of problem report from user you can navigate him to create some logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to.

1. Even if you're not printing anything, you're still executing `calculateThisAndThat()`.
2. It won't take a skilled reverse engineer a lot of time to reenable the console window.

That being said, in the future I suggest using a different logging routine (iostreams get a lot of bad rep for being slow), one that you'll be able to switch off with just one compile-time setting.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is very slow comparing to some c++ code.it might slow you significantly, so yes do not let it run on your release.